# Faster alternative to the command type?

Tags: windows, batch-file, types, prompt

Recently I've been looking for a command that can display a text file on the terminal, and fast. I can open this file in less than 1 second in notepad + + but with the type takes almost 25 seconds reading. Have any better alternative?

Comment: Why are you typing a long file to the screen if you aren't reading it? If you want to read the bottom of the file then a port of the `tail` command could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is not in opening and reading the file, it's the time taken to output it to a terminal screem.

If you're only interested in the last few lines of the file (and I assume that's the case unless you can read about a million times faster than regular mortals), you can use `tail` from either [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) (in coreutils). Assuming you don't need to full awesome power of a UNIX-like environment, I'd opt for the latter since it provides tools that can run standalone.

The command:

```
tail -50l input.txt
```

(for the last 50 lines) should work substantially faster than a full file output. It also gives you other nifty features like "following" a file that's being updated periodically.